# Sending a document to Stripe using Play! Scala 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, stripe-payments, multipartform-data, stripe-connect

I want to send a file to Stripe using Play! Scala 2.5.
The documentation says that the request should be (curl equivalent) like this:

```
curl https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files \
   -u sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2: \
   -F purpose=dispute_evidence \
   -F file="@/path/to/a/file.jpg"
```

Mine is:

```
def test: Action[MultipartFormData[TemporaryFile]] = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
  val image = request.body.file("picture").get

  val info = Map("purpose" -> Seq("identity_document"))
  val attachment =
    FilePart[TemporaryFile](
      key = "file",
      filename = "file",
      contentType = image.contentType,
      ref = image.ref)
  val formData: MultipartFormData[TemporaryFile] =
    MultipartFormData(
      dataParts = info,
      files = Seq(attachment),
      badParts = Seq.empty)

  import services.MultipartFormDataWritable.anyContentAsMultipartFormWritable

  wSClient
    .url("https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files")
    .withAuth("secret_key", "", WSAuthScheme.BASIC)
    .post(formData)
    .map(response => println(response.body))

  Ok
}
```

But Stripe returns me this `Bad Request error`:

```
"error": {
  "type": "invalid_request_error",
  "message": "Missing required param: file.",
  "param": "file"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
   val file = request.body.file("picture").get

      val filename = file.filename
      val contentType = file.contentType.getOrElse(logAndThrowException("Id card without content type"))

      if (contentType != "image/png" && contentType != "image/jpeg" && contentType != "image/jpg") {
        logAndThrowException("Wrong content type (jp[e]g or png required)")
      }

      val tmpFile = file.ref.file
      wSClient
        .url("https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files")
        .withAuth(stripeTestAPIKey, "", WSAuthScheme.BASIC)
        .withHeaders("Stripe-Account" -> stripeAccount)
        .post(
          Source(
            iterable =
              FilePart("file", filename, Option("text/plain"),
                FileIO.fromPath(tmpFile.toPath)) ::
                DataPart("purpose", "identity_document") ::
                List()))
```